# .net windows application store data offline and store to db when there is network

Tags: c#, sql, windows

I am developing a windows application for agricultural purpose. This application will be used by multiple users to maintain the data. The main issue is there won't be network connectivity on the work location. But however by end of the day they can go and synchronize if there are any option.

I just want to know how can we import and store all the data locally and update the data to database when there is network.

The options that i thought is to have SQL on every machine that runs this application. Store the data to local database when there is no network.

Having a separate button to export the local data to the centralized database when there is network.

Looks like this is complicated. Is there any better and easier option.

I prefer using c#, Visual studio.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the data complex to sync? Is there updating of data that will take place in "offline" mode or is it simply adding new data? Is there any danger of having data modified by multiple people at the same time in offline mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. Please find the below solution that we implemented.

1) Installed SQL express on all the local machines

2) Used Microsoft Sync framework to sync the data. The sync is configured on demand.

Issues faced:

1) We were using geometry datatype on few tables and this was not supported by sync framework.

2) Any change in the database schema will not reflect on the client machine. We will have to delete all the system generated procedures used to track the table change and regenerate it. I am sure there will be a much better way to do this.

Cheers,
Jebli

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) for storing data locally. It's fast, lightweight, and public domain.

You can use whatever the database of choice for the centralized server.

Comment: Agree - SQL Lite is a great choice for local data storage, as then you don't need to install something like SQL server. You can use Entity Framework to connect to it (we had problems with EF 6, but EF 5 works well). There's a handy firefox plugin available to give you a GUI for setting up the initial database too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this a quite broad question, as it has many options and scenarios. The questions you should ask yourself are:

1. Does user handle new information only or any information from any other user from the previous syncing?
2. Do you have to handle update conflicts?
3. Do you handle text information only or you have complex types and binary files?

As for the solution, the easiest way, from my point of view, would be using SQL Lite on portable devices, is a lightweight SQL client that will allow you to handle information easily. On the server you can use whatever you want, SQL Server, MySQL or any other SQL flavor you may like. Just make sure there is a connector for your portable device OS.

If you keep thinking of using SQL server on the portable device, it's a battery hogger!!!, you might want to check [Microsoft Sync framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb902854%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), as it provides almost all possible scenarios for handling data syncing, manage conflicts, etc.